# cmb2 meta data in save_post filter

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, wordpress-hook, cmb2

I want to access metabox data in save_post filter of wordpress . but I cant access to these meta data because the metabox data writed in post_meta table after post publish...

I also use metabox.io plugin and I can access to data in save_post filter.

how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with set high priority to add_action or add_filter of save_post hook
The cmb2 use add_action with  10 priority... You only need use higher than 10.

```
    add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_function_on_save', 11 );
```

Hooks a function on to a specific action.